# Gradle Equivalent for Maven Dependency?

Tags: maven, gradle, pom.xml

**What is the equivalent Gradle notation for the following maven part?**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.goodow.realtime</groupId>
  <artifactId>realtime-json</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
  <classifier>sources</classifier>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I suppose it is something like:

```
compile com.goodow.realtime:realtime-json:30
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write following code in you build script for defining classifier

```
compile group: 'com.goodow.realtime', name: 'realtime-json', version: '3.0', classifier: 'sources'
```

Comment: If you want to map `provided` scope, use `compileOnly`

Answer (score 0):

By default, Gradle doesn't have a `provided` scope configuration.
This can be added as follows:

```
// Declare a 'provided' configuration
configurations {
    provided
}

// Add the 'provided' configuration dependencies to the compile classpath 
sourceSets.main { 
    compileClasspath += configurations.provided
}
```

You can then use this configuration to declare a dependency as follows:

```
dependencies {
     provided "com.goodow.realtime:realtime-json:3.0"

     // Other dependencies
}
```